# How do I include the node_modules in electron-forge webpack?

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

The `@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader` works in some modules, and does not work in some. In cases that it doesn't work, I have to use the externals config as stated in the electron-forge docs [here.](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#native-modules)

> If the asset relocator loader does not work for your native module, you may want to consider using the [externals configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

So what ended up happening is me putting the modules in the externals config like so:

```js
// webpack.main.config.js

module.exports = {
  // other webpack configs
  externals: {
    'active-win': 'commonjs2 active-win',
    iohook: 'commonjs2 iohook',
    'screenshot-desktop': 'commonjs2 screenshot-desktop',
  },
};
```

What this does is, it will search the node_modules folder whenever those modules are used. This works in development but once the app is packaged, the node_modules folder is empty.

I tried to use [@timfish/forge-externals-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@timfish/forge-externals-plugin) library but it doesn't work on some modules that I use.

So how do I make it such that the node_modules folder is included in the packaged app? I'm not sure if this is an electron config or webpack config or both. Thanks...

Comment: Hi, did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: Either of you have any luck? I too have the same issue with serialport module

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this problem? Struggling to solve this problem for a week?

Comment: I am stuck in a similar issue as well. Any luck with this?